# Dropdown form overlaps in boostrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to implement a dropdown with an input but whenever I try to click the dropdown, it overlaps to the other row of the table since the inputs are inside the table. Please see my screenshot below.

Screenshot:

[image]

Note: This is pure bootstrap 3, and didn't add any customization yet.

Comment: please create a snippet of your code

Comment: share code snippet here or on jsfiddle and share url. that will help us what is the issue